# Trouble with showing time in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I created an easy game with Javascript, the purpose is to pick a square who has a RGB color(random generated) from a list of squares and show the length of time until the square with the correct color is found.  Everything works fine, except after the time is shown corectly and I click on a button, the time continues to change and show again a new time and i don't want that. I try to give display: none  or textcontent ="" after showing the time, but is not working. 
The problem is in these lines:

```
            end = new Date().getTime();
            timeTaken = (end - start) / 1000;
            timp.style.display ="inline";
            timp.innerHTML = "Timpul tau: " + timeTaken + " s.";
```

Thanks!

The game link: https://ionutbedeoan.github.io/joc/

My javascript code :

```
var numSquares = 6;
var colors = generateRandomColors(numSquares);
var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var pickedColor = pickColor();
var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay");
var messageDisplay = document.querySelector("#message");
var h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
var resetButton = document.querySelector("#reset");
var easyBtn = document.querySelector("#easyBtn");
var hardBtn = document.querySelector("#hardBtn");
var numSquares = 6;
var timp = document.getElementById("timeTaken");
var start = new Date().getTime();
var end;
var timeTaken;



easyBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    start = new Date().getTime();
    numSquares = 3;
    this.classList.add("selected");
    hardBtn.classList.remove("selected");
    colors = generateRandomColors(numSquares);
    pickedColor = pickColor();
    colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    }
    for (var i = 3; i < squares.length; i++) {
        squares[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    timp.textContent= "";
       messageDisplay.textContent = "";
    h1.style.background = "steelblue";
});
hardBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    start = new Date().getTime();
    this.classList.add("selected");
    numSquares = 6;
    easyBtn.classList.remove("selected");
    colors = generateRandomColors(numSquares);
    pickedColor = pickColor();
    colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;
    for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
        squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
        squares[i].style.display = "block";
    }
    messageDisplay.textContent = "";
    timp.textContent= "";
    h1.style.background = "steelblue";
});

resetButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    start = new Date().getTime();
    //generare noi culori
    colors = generateRandomColors(numSquares);
    //alegem o noua culoare random din vector
    pickedColor = pickColor();
    //schimbam colorDisplay sa fie la fel cu culoarea aleasa
    colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;
    //schimbare culori ale patratelor
    for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
        // adaug culorile la fiecare patrat
        squares[i].style.background = colors[i];
    }
    h1.style.background = "steelblue";
    messageDisplay.textContent = "";
    this.textContent = "Culori noi";
   timp.textContent= "";

});

colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;

for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    // adaug culorile la fiecare patrat
    squares[i].style.background = colors[i];
    //cand dau click pe un patrat
    squares[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        // pun intr-o variabila culoarea patratatului ca sa o verific cu culoarea pe care trebuie sa o ghicesc, pentru a vedea daca am nimerit culoarea
        var clickedColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
        if (clickedColor === pickedColor) {
            messageDisplay.textContent = "Corect!"
            resetButton.textContent = "Joc nou"
            changeColors(clickedColor);
            h1.style.backgroundColor = clickedColor;
            end = new Date().getTime();
            timeTaken = (end - start) / 1000;
            timp.style.display ="inline";
            timp.innerHTML = "Timpul tau: " + timeTaken + " s.";




        } else {
            this.style.backgroundColor = "#232323";
            messageDisplay.textContent = "Gresit!";

        }
    });
};

function changeColors(color) {
    //schimbam culoarea la fiecare patrat
    for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
        squares[i].style.backgroundColor = color;

    }

}

function pickColor() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    return colors[random];


}

function generateRandomColors(num) {
    // fac un vector
    var arr = [];
    //adaugam numarul de culori random
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        //alegem o culoare random si o bagam in vector
        arr[i] = randomColor();
    }
    //returnam vectorul
    return arr;

}

function randomColor() {
    // alegem un rosu intre 0 si 255
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    //alegem un verde intre 0 si 255
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    //alegem un albastru intre 0 si 255
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    return "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";

}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Check if the correct answer was already selected in your square's event listener and return if so. This will prevent it from running the rest of the event listener's code where it updates the time.

```
if (clickedColor === pickedColor) {
  if (messageDisplay.textContent === "Corect!") return;
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```